# Numerical convergence and minimum number size

Tags: perl, floating-point, precision

I have a program which calculates probability values
([*p*-values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value)),
but it is entering a very large negative number into the
`exp` function
`exp(-626294.830)` which evaluates to zero instead of the very small
positive number that it should be.

How can I get this to evaluate as a very small floating point number?
I have tried
[`Math::BigFloat`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigFloat),
[`bignum`](https://metacpan.org/pod/bignum), and 
[`bigrat`](https://metacpan.org/pod/bigrat)
but all have failed.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, maybe just because I don't know what your pvalues are. Can you post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please?

Comment: Are you sure it "hangs", or does it just take longer to run? If you get the correct results with `use bignum;`/`use bigrat;`, and incorrect results without, that would be an important diagnostic.

Comment: @Robert I've added a mcve at the end, it's basically how can I get `exp(large negative number)` to evaluate as a very small positive float instead of `0`?

Comment: @haukex the program runs more than 5 min 42 seconds (I stopped).  It should run in about 20 milliseconds.

Comment: @con Unfortunately that doesn't answer my question though, since the important part is whether the program truly "hangs" (never returns), or whether it *works* - that it runs slowly with those modules is to be expected.

Comment: @con: What you have written isn't even close to an MCVE. You need to read the link [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that [**Robert** posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723654/numerical-convergence-and-minimum-number-size#comment84446195_48723654).

Comment: @borodin I re-wrote this several times in order to address the problem in as brief a manner as possible.  If you're going to downvote me, write down *explicitly* what is wrong, it is far too easy to downvote and just complain.

Comment: @con: *"If you're going to downvote me, write down explicitly what is wrong, it is far too easy to downvote and just complain"* You are in no position to demand anything from me; *Stack Overflow* provides anonymous voting, and you need to abide by the rules of the site. As far as I can see you currently have no votes at all either way, and I certainly didn't cast any. You will find that a lack of commentary on the votes you receive is far from the worst experience you will encounter, and rants about injustice will be quickly be deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) says that `exp(-626294.830)` is 4.08589×10^-271997... zero is a pretty close approximation to that `;-)` Although you've edited and removed the context from your question, do you really need to work with such tiny numbers, or perhaps there is some way you could optimize your algorithm or scale your numbers?

Anyway, you are correct that code like `Math::BigFloat->new("-626294.830")->bexp` seems to take quite some time, even with the support of `use Math::BigFloat lib => 'GMP';`.

The only alternative I can offer at the moment is [`Math::Prime::Util::GMP`'s `expreal`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Prime::Util::GMP#expreal), although you need to specify a precision to it.

```
use Math::Prime::Util::GMP qw/expreal/;
use Math::BigFloat;
my $e = Math::BigFloat->new(expreal(-626294.830,272000));
print $e->bnstr,"\n";
__END__
4.086e-271997
```

But on my machine, even that still takes ~20s to run, which brings us back to the question of potential optimization in other places.

Answer (score 4):

Floating point numbers do not have infinite precision. Assuming the number is represented as an IEEE 754 double, we have 52 bits for a fraction, 11 bits for the exponent, and one bit for the sign. Due to the way exponents are encoded, the smallest positive number that can be represented is 2^-1022.

If we look at your number e^-626294.830, we can do a change of base and see that it equals 2^(log_2 e · -626294.830) = 2^-903552.445, which is significantly smaller than 2^-1022. Approximating your number as zero is therefore correct.

Instead of calculating this value using arbitrary-precision numerics, you are likely better off solving the necessary equations *by hand*, then coding this in a way that does not require extreme precision. For example, it is unlikely that you need the exact value of e^-626294.830, but perhaps just the magnitude. Then, you can calculate the logarithm instead of using exp().